# On MarkLogic using xquery, which is faster for joining strings, fn:concat or pipe (||) joining?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there a difference in speed between these two ways of joining strings?

```
fn:concat("Test1 ", "Test2")

"Test1 " || "Test2"
```

Comment: Measure it and see. I don't know the internals of the product, but I would expect that the function and the operator compile to exactly the same executable code. And if there's a performance difference, I would think it highly unlikely it will be noticeable on your bottom line. If you have a performance problem, you are looking in the wrong place for a solution; if you don't have a performance problem, then why are you looking at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are literally exactly the same. This is handled in the parser.